# how to install fglrx driver on debian testing when the package has been removed from testing?

Tags: drivers, debian, amd-graphics-card

[Debian tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/fglrx-driver) says that the fglrx drivers have been removed from stretch / testing

I tried to install the stable version but the modules aren't building on the 4.3 kernel the testing is currently using.

I tried to install the sid / unstable version of the drivers, but I end up in a massive conflict with xserver-xorg I can't seem to solve, so either I got the drivers, either I got X

I'd be interested to see if there is a solution at the moment to install those drivers on stretch ?